# how to use bracket when I want to extract substring matching a regex in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I know basic way to extract string matching a regex in scala:

```
val p = ".*(\\d+ minutes).*".r
val p(m) = "last 12 minutes."
```

I can get "12 minutes" in m.
But what if I want to match regex like `\\d+ minute(s)?`. For example, I could get `"12 minutes"` if input is `"last 12 minutes."`, and `"12 minute"` if input is `"last 12 minute."`.

`".*(\\d+ minute(s)?).*".r` doesn't work, maybe bracket is used to mark the matched regex we want, so more brackets appeared in regex doesn't work. And I know `".*(\\d+ minute[s]?).*".r` could satisfy my request, but what if I want to match `\\d+ minutes( left)?` in which case I have to use bracket in the matched part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a [`?` modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (`s?`) to make a single char optional or a [**non-capturing group**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) with a `?` quantifier to make a sequence of chars (here, `(?:s)?`) optional:

```
val p = ".*?(\\d+ minutes?).*".r
```

Or with a non-capturing group:

```
val p = ".*?(\\d+ minute(?:s)?).*".r
val p = ".*\\b(\\d+ minutes(?: left)?).*".r
```

Note that you must make the first `.*` lazy or you won't be able to get `12` into the capturing group. Or use a word boundary, `".*\\b(\\d+ minutes?).*".r`, or make the regex unanchored and get rid of `.*` altogether:

```
val p = """(\d+\s+minutes?)""".r.unanchored
val s = "last 12 minutes."
val res = s match { 
    case p(m) => m
    case _ => ""
}
// => 12 minutes
```

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/oSSIWe).

Comment: Thanks a lot, "non-capturing group", that's what I want. Also thx about the advice for unanchored.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark `?` will by default refer to the immediately preceding character.  So the following should match `minute` or `minutes`:

```
val p = ".*(\\d+ minutes?).*".r
```